# Hook or callback to write a header value before the first body byte in express.js

Tags: express, events, cookies, httpresponse

In some global application-level middleware in express.js (4.16.4) and node.js (10.15.1) I would like to write a cookie to the header at the very last opportunity before any middleware writes the first byte of a body to the response object.

For example, imagining there is a `beforeWriteBody` event on the `Response` object, we could do something like this:

```
res.on('beforeWriteResponseBody', res => {
    res.cookie('key', 'value');
});
```

Recognizing that this event could also be listened to by other recipients and they could write headers after this function, still, this would be very useful to me as it could help avoid writing this cookie value multiple times, as I don't know in advance where in the pipeline the cookie value could be updated before the actual first byte of the response body is written.

Async would be fine, such that if any listener to this event attempted to write bytes to the response body and there were still other listeners in the list to be called afterward, that body-writing listener could be paused and the remaining listeners could be called, then execution returned to the body writer (though execution order could be tricky, if it was just enforced to be the order of the listener attachment, I still think it could be reasonable).

I want to persist something in a cookie, but with the freedom to modify that cookie multiple times without writing multiple duplicate Set-Cookie headers, but have this reliably occur no matter what response was written, even a `res.redirect()` for example.

Looking at the express.js source code, I see a possible point to dig in, [`res.send() in response.js](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L107).

After eyeballing it for a bit, it seems like my `beforeWriteResponseBody` would be getting called before the first action of node's [`request.end`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback).

I see there are events in node that are close to what I want, such as[`finish`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) which is triggered *after* `end` has been called. But I need an event that triggers before `res.write` or `res.end` have been called (or after they've been called, but before they do any work).

Answer (score 0):

Express does not support hooks / callbacks in the form you want.

Overall, it's bad for you approach this. JS allows you to easily overwrite any function, in this case you have to do it like this:

```js
var app = express();

let _end = express.response.end
express.response.send = function() {
    if(!this.headersSent)
        console.log('can overwrite')
    _end.apply(this, arguments)
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, you can use `headersSent`, otherwise you have to take care of one-time calling techniques, eg by adding a flag to`res`.

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean by "it's bad for you approach this"? You offered the suggestion of modifying express's own methods, which I considered, but I don't really like that as it ties me into comprehensively covering every possible way express allows one to get bytes into the response body. I'm not sure that's a great thing, but maybe it's the only possible way.

Comment: You did not write that you were considering this solution. There is no event you need so you have to overwrite the method anyway. You do not need to pack the service there. You can call an event there. (But I do not know how to do it nicely)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to wait until the last minute to write the headers. Every time that you might want to write headers, you can examine the existing ones and remove any you don't want. This gives you that last-chance opportunity to ensure the headers are correct, without multiple copies of the header being placed into the response.

This works even if there are some headers with the same name that you don't want to touch.

Here's a really rough implementation of how that might work:

```
const removeUnsentHeaderFromResponseHeaders = (res, headerName, exclusionFilter) => {
  let headerValues = res.get(headerName);
  if (!headerValues) {
    return;
  }
  if (!Array.isArray(headerValues)) {
    headerValues = [headerValues];
  }
  res.header(headerName, headerValues.filter(value => !exclusionFilter(value)));
};
```

And here's an example usage:

```
// We want to set header 'My-Header', which can be set multiple times
// but also want to remove any that I've already set during this request.
// The ones my code has already set will contain `my-special-flag`.

removeUnsentHeaderFromResponseHeaders(
    res,
    'My-Header',
    headerValue => headerValue.includes('my-special-flag')
);
res.set('My-Header', 'The full my-special-flag value that should overwrite');
```

Simply do this every time you set `My-Header` and you will be avoiding sending extra, useless header values in the response.